# Generating shell scripts using python

Tags: python, linux, sh, silent-installer

Hi I'm currently working on a python script that generates shell scripts to install agents on a linux server. The .sh files that the python scripts output keeps ending up with a "syntax error: unexpected end of file" but when i manually type in the exact output in vi, there seems to be no issue. Is there any issue with how I'm writing it in python or is it feasible to do it through python?

python script

```
import csv

def menu():
    print("type of scripts")
    print("1. Install + Generation")
    print("2. Unregister + Reregister")
    print("3. Unregister + Uninstall")

#Converts numeral choice into type for script naming
def choicename(choice):
    choice = int(choice)
    if choice==1:
        return "install"
    elif choice == 2 :
        return "rereg"
    else:
        return "uninstall"

#Generates the install agent scripts    
def installScript(agentname,agentfile,mgrfile,prigw,secgw,ostype):
    #Generates the script for Linux agents (.sh)
    if ostype=="Linux":
        agentpath = 'agent="/opt/test/ragent/bin/racli"'
        installerpath = '\ninstaller="/opt/test/installer/bin/racli"'

        checkAgent = '\nif [ ! -e "$agent" ]; then' +"\n" + "./" + agentfile + " -n -d /opt/test" + '\nelse\necho "Agent is already installed"\nfi'
        checkInstaller = '\nif [ ! -e "$installer" ]; then' + "\n" +"./" + mgrfile + " -n -d /opt/test"+ '\nelse\necho "Manager is already installed"\nfi'

        regAgent = "\n/opt/test/ragent/bin/cli registration advanced-register registration-type=Primary ragent-name="+ agentname+ " gw-ip="+ prigw+ " gw-port=443 manual-settings-activation=Automatic monitor-networkchannels=Both password=$1"
        if secgw!="":
            regAgent+="\n/opt/test/ragent/bin/cli registration advanced-register registration-type=Secondary ragent-name="+ agentname+ " gw-ip="+ secgw+ " gw-port=443 manual-settings-activation=Automatic monitor-networkchannels=Both password=$1"
        startAgent="\n/opt/test/ragent/bin/rainit start"

        regInstaller="\n/opt/test/installer/bin/cliinstaller registration register-use-existing package-folder-path=\".\" package-folder-size=1024"
        startInstaller="\n/opt/test/installer/bin/rainstallerinit start"

        sf = open(agentname+ "_install.sh","w")
        sf.write(agentpath+installerpath+checkAgent+checkInstaller+regAgent+startAgent+regInstaller+startInstaller)
        sf.close()


def scriptSplit(option,agentname,agentfile,mgrfile,prigw,secgw,ostype):
    if option=="install":
        installScript(agentname,agentfile,mgrfile,prigw,secgw,ostype)
    elif option =="rereg":
        reregScript(agentname,agentfile,mgrfile,prigw,secgw,ostype)
    elif option =="uninstall":
        uninstallScript()

#Collects user input for function type
def main():
    menu()
    choice = input("Please choose the type of script you would like to generate: ")
    option = choicename(choice)
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the csv file: ")

    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        creader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        line_count = 0
        for row in creader:
            if line_count!=0:
                agentname=row[0]
                agentfile=row[1]
                mgrfile=row[2]
                prigw=row[3]
                secgw=row[4]
                installtype=row[5]
                scriptSplit(option,agentname,agentfile,mgrfile,prigw,secgw,installtype)
            line_count += 1
#### END OF FUNCTIONS ###

main()
```

output from above script

```
agent="/opt/test/ragent/bin/racli"
installer="/opt/test/installer/bin/racli"
if [ ! -e "$agent" ]; then
./agent1.bsx -n -d /opt/test
else
echo "Agent is already installed"
fi
if [ ! -e "$installer" ]; then
./installer1.bsx -n -d /opt/test
else
echo "Manager is already installed"
fi
/opt/test/ragent/bin/cli registration advanced-register registration-type=Primary ragent-name=agent1 gw-ip=10.255.0.80 gw-port=443 manual-settings-activation=Automatic monitor-networkchannels=Both password=$1
/opt/test/ragent/bin/cli registration advanced-register registration-type=Secondary ragent-name=agent1 gw-ip=10.255.0.81 gw-port=443 manual-settings-activation=Automatic monitor-networkchannels=Both password=$1
/opt/test/ragent/bin/rainit start
/opt/test/installer/bin/cliinstaller registration register-use-existing package-folder-path="." package-folder-size=1024
/opt/test/installer/bin/rainstallerinit start
```

csv file it reads from

```
Agent Name,Agent File,Installer File,Primary IP,Secondary IP,Type
agent1,agent1.bsx,installer1.bsx,10.255.0.80,10.255.0.81,Linux
agent2,agent2.bsx,installer2.bsx,10.255.0.81,,Linux
```

Comment: What does `diff` say when you compare your output and your manually typed shell script?

Comment: The script is fine and should work. What does output `syntax error: unexpected end of file`? Is this the exact error message? Is there a `bash:` in front of it? Try adding `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of the script.

Comment: @Błotosmętek it says theres no newline at end of file.

Comment: @KamilCuk ./agent1_install.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file 
this is the error i got when i tried running the generated script. i got the same error when i copy pasted the script into an online script checker

Comment: I've noticed that comparing the two scripts in vi, the generated script has a [noeol][dos] at the bottom as compared to the one manually typed in. Is it possible to do something about it from python ?

Comment: So you have dos line endings? Try ex. `dos2unix`. That's strange. Someone who knows python better should come, I see there is `newline=` parameter that is passed to `open`. Are you running the python script from windows?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes i'm running the python script from windows at the moment. i'll need to do a windows version of the script in the near future as well so i was hoping to use python so i can run it from either platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [newline convention](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) is `\r\n` on windows. Bash interprets newline character as... newline character, and the `\r` is a normal character for `bash`.

Fix:

```
sf = open(agentname+ "_install.sh", "w", newline='\n')
```

Comment: ah i see thank you so much for your help! guess it's something i would need to take note of when working on different platforms :x